How to allocate more than 4GB for android emulators?
I have an Android emulator setup in my CI server. I notice that when I boot it up with more than 4GB of RAM eg.
emulator -avd myEmulator -m 6144

, a warning message appears:
pc_memory_init: above 4g size: 4000000

When I check my RAM size using adb, it is fell back to 4GB.
How to allocate more than 4GB for the emulator ?

It turns out that using this command line after emulator is booted:
adb shell “cat /proc/meminfo”

I'm able to see that the RAM size allocated for emulator is exactly what I put in the command line:
emulator -avd myEmulator -m ${RAM_SIZE}


You can adjust your memory settings used by the android studio as well as the emulators using the settings provided below.


Adjust your memory settings as per your requirements.

Are you sure modifying a setting for Android Studio affects the emulator on the CI server?

That settings are for the IDE itself, and for Gradle and Kotlin daemon. The emulator is a separate process independent of Android Studio IDE (even if the window is shows as part of the IDE).

In my CI server, I have android-sdk, I don't have Android Studio. However, this answer could help someone with their emulators in their laptops.
